# In Django, how do I move a file from a model to a directory on disk?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which stores a .exe file. I want to take that file out of the model and paste it in a specific folder without altering the model. Any ideas?

The model is something like this:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    program_name = models.CharField(...)
    program_version = models.CharField(...)
    program_installer = models.FileField(...)
```

I need to be able to extract the program installer from the model, sever any connection it has with the model itself and then put a new file in the model (while keeping the older installer i a separate place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileField` by default use [`django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage), so it contains a **string with file name (path to a file)**, not a file itself. Just use that filename (path) to copy a file to destination you need.

From here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#using-files-in-models:

> When you use a FileField or ImageField, Django provides a set of APIs
>   you can use to deal with that file.
>
> Consider the following model, using an ImageField to store a photo:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Car(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
>     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
>     photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cars')
> ```
>
> Any Car instance will have a photo attribute that you can use to get
>   at the details of the attached photo:
>
> ```
> >>> car = Car.objects.get(name="57 Chevy")
> >>> car.photo
> <ImageFieldFile: chevy.jpg>
> >>> car.photo.name
> 'cars/chevy.jpg'
> >>> car.photo.path
> '/media/cars/chevy.jpg'
> >>> car.photo.url
> 'http://media.example.com/cars/chevy.jpg'
> ```

Comment: Thanks. That was my first idea, but I thought there was a better way.